# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 637: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8, iso-8859-1

This is driving me crazy and i have tried different suggestions from the community but it doesnt seem to work. I tried even recreating the db using just utf-8 and still it gives me this error.

Basically i am using pymysql module and writing to the db.

```
openconnect = pymysql.connect(host='xxxx',port=3306,user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxxx')
opencursor = openconnect.cursor()
```

one of my column is having the problem, basically i tried these options...

the columns that cause issue is subject and i tried the below

```
subject = (df.Subject[i])

subject.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
```

and then try to write to the db it fails.
if i try `subject.encode('latin-1')` also it fails.

I have two options, either fix the encoding or how i can set the coalition on pymysql to use utf-8 ? I verified the db, coalition on mysql is set to utf-8. Really appreciate your input on this..

still struggling with this.
cheers
Kabeer

Comment: somehow formating issue  subject = (df.Subject[i]) and on the next line subject.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`    Add this line on top of your script.

Comment: I just tried that.. and still it gives the same error

Comment: sql = sql.encode(self.encoding, 'surrogateescape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 637: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon: 1- `subject` is not a literal string and therefor the encoding declaration such as `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` has no effect on it. The declaration may affect only the characters inside string literals in your source. 2- Even if it did affect it; it wouldn't matter: `'\u2013'` is a string literal that contains only ascii characters (the unicode character is represented using the unicode escape sequence). There is no difference between latin-1 and utf-8 in the ascii range.

Comment: @NKB: surely `mysql` provides a way to configure the character encoding used for the db connection (use `utf-8`, to be able to represent all Unicode characters. You might need some fine-tuning if your data may contain lone surrogates).

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with mysql configuration.  You might want to add that tag to your question

Comment: Right, stop. Please give a short piece of code, so we can reproduce your problem (See [mcve]). Then give us the whole stack trace with your error. Also, why are you trying to `encode`?

Comment: Also, the tags say both Py3k and py2.7. Is it really both?

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve the issue by defining a charset in `pymysql` connect:

```
openconnect = pymysql.connect(
  host='xxxx',port=3306,user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxxx',charset='utf8'
)
```

Please note it is `utf8` and not `utf-8`.

Comment: Don't know why the downvotes. I got the same issue and `charset='utf8'` resolved it. Thanks :)